# Debugging in Visual Studio Code without breakpoints, checking the function calls stack

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to dive in a really big codebase. I am using Visual Studio Code. I always used debugger with setting the breakpoints, but this time I just would like to become familiar with a new codebase and see where is the code responsible for particular program commands execution. Is there an option to run debugger step by step without setting breakpoints in VSC? Or where can I find e.g. what functions where called during my program execution? In Call Stack section I see only the threads number.

Answer (score 0):

I see a command

```
editor.debug.action.runToCursor
```

if you don't want to set breakpoints.  It has no default binding so you will have to make your own.  I tested it and it works.  When your code stops  - at your cursor - you should see the call stack (assuming the call stack panel is not hidden).